# Why is 'ROUND(variable)' not working in my SQL code using DBeaver and Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, syntax-error, rounding, dbeaver

I'm learning SQL, and I'm working on DBeaver with Postgres 15 on Windows 10. I am trying to calculate a problem given to me by Codecademy. Here it is:

/*This award goes to the team that had the smallest
“cost per win” in 2010. Cost per win is determined by
the total salary of the team divided by the number of
wins in a given year. Note that we decided to look at
just teams in 2010 because when we found this award
looking across all years, we found that due to inflation,
teams from the 1900s spent much less money per win. We
thought that looking at all teams in just the year 2010
gave a more interesting statistic.*/

And here is my code:

```
WITH total_salary AS
(
        SELECT
        SUM(salaries.salary) AS "salary_sum",
        teams.name AS "team_name",
        salaries.yearid AS "year_id",
        teams.w AS "wins"
    FROM salaries
    JOIN teams
        ON salaries.team_id = teams.id
    WHERE salaries.yearid = 2010
    GROUP BY
        teams.name, teams.w, salaries.yearid
    ORDER BY
        teams.w DESC
),
cost_per_win_raw AS 
(
    SELECT 
        (salary_sum / wins) AS "cost_per_win_num"
    FROM total_salary
)
SELECT
    ROUND(cost_per_win_num, 2) AS "cost_per_win"
FROM cost_per_win_raw
GROUP BY cost_per_win
ORDER BY cost_per_win DESC;
```

My question is why isn't ( ROUND(cost_per_win_num), 2) AS "cost_per_win" ) working?
It throws me this error every time:

```
SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: function round(double precision, integer) does not exist
Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
Position: 448
```

NOTE: teams.w is smallint and salaries.salary is double precision.

Comment: Per [Math functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-math.html): *round ( v numeric, s integer ) → numeric*.  So do `CAST`:  `ROUND(cost_per_win_num::numeric, 2)`. Though I am not sure how you are getting `double precision` as Postgres does `integer` division on integers: `select 1/2; 0` and `select pg_typeof(1/2); integer`.  You might want to verify the types of  `salary_sum / wins` and `salary` and `wins`.

Comment: Ok, so I was wrong about the data types. salary is double precision and wins is smallint.

Comment: Then you will need to add the `CAST` per my previous comment.

Comment: That gives me this error:  SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near ":"
Position: 452
Error position: line: 193 pos: 451

Comment: Add the modified code to your question.  It should be `cost_per_win_num::numeric`, note the two `:` If DBeaver does not like that notation try `CAST(cost_per_win_num AS numeric)`

Comment: There's no point in using `order by` with the first cte. Some systems would even give an error there. Ii doubt there's a justifiable purpose for the final `group by` on the calculated value.

Comment: Ok, I figured it out! I changed the data types of those two columns to numeric, and then the code ran like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: That was overkill,  since unless there are fractional wins `integer` is the proper type for that. A temporary `CAST` is something you will be using often when creating queries so it is a good idea to learn how. Especially given that you usually will not have the ability to change the types in the table.